# How to use .h file in swift project ? .h is written in c++

Tags: c++, ios, swift, static-libraries

I have one pre-compiled library with .h and .a files, I want to use these file into my newly created project which uses swift, but library used C++. I have added this library into my workspace and also can see these libraries into "Search Library Path" , "Build Phases/Link Binary with Libraries", but when I am trying to import it is giving error like: "**Expected identifier in import declaration**". Here I have also mentioned statement which I written to import:

**import "AppLibraries/VCamLib/Header.h"**.

This is my first IOS project so please help me to link pre-build static library into my swift project.

Comment: Seem like you did not have the `Bridging-Header.h` file in your project, did you?

Comment: yes I do have...!

Comment: Swift can't interface with C++ code. You need a C layer in between.

Comment: Yes for that I have added Bridging-Header